# Selenium webdriver - action.sendkeys() : notworking

Tags: selenium, webdriver, sendkeys

I'm trying to test one specific Selenium's *Actions* class method, which is as below.

```
public Actions sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keysToSend)
```

Sends keys to the active element. This differs from calling `WebElement.sendKeys(CharSequence...)` on the active element.

```
public class Demo_1 {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private Actions action;
  private String baseUrl;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\ProgramFiles\\firefox.exe");
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(file);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);
    action = new Actions(driver);
    baseUrl = "http://www.mortgagecalculator.org";
  }

  @Test
  public void testUntitled() throws Exception { 
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("param[homevalue]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("param[homevalue]")).clear();
    action.sendKeys("300000");
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    //driver.quit();
  }
}
```

I can do this alternatively, but in some cases when there is no WebElement, `action.sendKeys` can help to send CharSequence without any WebElement as parameter.

Can some come up with similar kind of issue, as the above code is not working :(

Answer (score 4):

Cause its Actions class object so you need to tell the driver the actions you are performing.

> **action.sendKeys("300000").perform();**

Will do the needful.